# Зеркальный рендер после упаковки проекта Unreal Engine 5.1 для PICO VR

Tags: render, unreal-engine-5, vr

При запуске собранного проекта на гарнитуре PICO 4 картинка отображается полностью в зеркальном виде (зеркалится и по горизонтали и по вертикали).
[image: Скрин вида из очков PICO 4]
*скрин с гарнитуры PICO 4*

- Пробовал SDK PICO для UE с маркета эпиков и с офф сайта PICO.
- Android Studio 4 версии:

1. стоят Android SDK Platform 28, 29, 30
2. SDK Build-tools 28.0.3, 29.0.3, 30.0.3
3. NDK 25.1.8937393

Один из проектов создавался под Oculus Quest. Никаких проблем с упаковкой и рендером не наблюдалось. В конце решили сменить платформу на PICO 4.

Пробовал стандартный пиковский проект с оф сайта - собирается так же в зеркальном отображении... Ошибок при компиляции не выдает.
Вот [**ЛОГ**](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/msztYqGIOZ4u4Q)